# How lighting in building games with unlimited number of lights works?

Tags: opengl, graphics, lighting

In Minecraft for example, you can place torches anywhere and each one effects the light level in the world and there is no limit to the amount of torches / light sources you can put down in the world.  I am 99% sure that the lighting for the torches is taken care of on the CPU and stored for each block and so when rendering the light value at that certain block just needs to be passed into the shader, but light sources cannot move for this reason.  If you had a game where you could place light sources that could move around (arrow on fire, minecart with a light on it, glowing ball of energy) and the lighting wasn't as simple (color was included) what are the most efficient ways to calculate the lighting effects.

From my research I have found differed rendering, differed lighting, dynamically creating shaders with different amounts of lights available and using a for loop (can't use uniforms due to unrolling), and static light maps (these would probably only be used for the still lights).  Are there any other ways to do lighting calculations such as doing what minecraft does except allowing moving lights, or is it possible to take an infinite amount of lights and mathematically combine them into an approximation that only involves a few lights (this is an idea I came up with but I can't figure out how it could be done)?

If it helps, I am a programmer with decent experience in OpenGL (legacy and modern) so you can give me code snippets although I have not done too much with lighting so brief explanations would be appreciated.  I am also willing to do research if you can point me in the right direction!

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use uniforms due to unrolling"? Tiled deferred rendering and forward+ rendering are two of the most powerful techniques, but they need to loop over a uniform that contain the number of lights.

Comment: From what I read, when shaders are compiled the compiler unrolls loops and so in a for loop the number of times that you are iterating through it must be a constant.

Comment: That's only true for WebGL 1.0 and OpenGL ES 2.0. If your target platform is a PC, you will not have this restriction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your title is a bit misleading `infinite light` implies directional light in infinite distance like Sun. I would use `unlimited number of lights` instead. Here some approaches for this I know of:

1. **(back) ray-tracers**

   they can handle any number of light sources natively. Light is just another object in engine. If ray hits the light source it just take the light intensity and stop the recursion. Unfortunately current gfx hardware is not suited for this kind of rendering. There are **GPU** enhanced engines for this but the specialized gfx HW is still in development and did not hit the market yet. Memory requirements are not much different then standard **BR** rendering and You can still use **BR** meshes but mathematical (analytical) meshes are natively supported and are better for this.
2. **Standard BR rendering**

   **BR** means `boundary representation` such engines (Like **OpenGL** fixed function) can handle only limited number of lights. This is because each **primitive/fragment** needs the complete list of lights and the computations are done for all light on per **primitive** or per **fragment** basis. If you got many light this would be slow.

   - [GLSL example of fixed number of light sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214) see the fragment shader

   Also the current GPU's have limited memory for uniforms (registers) in which the lights and other rendering parameters are stored so there are possible workarounds like have light parameters stored in a **texture** and iterate over all of them per **primitive/fragment** inside **GLSL** shader but the number of lights affect performance of coarse so you are limited by target frame-rate and computational power. Additional memory requirements for this is just the texture with light parameters which is not so much (few vectors per light).
3. **light maps**

   they can be computed even for moving objects. Complex light maps can be computed slowly (not per frame). This leads to small lighting artifacts but you need to know what to look for to spot it. Light maps and shadow maps are very similar and often computed at once. There are simple light maps and complex radiation maps models out there

   - look [Shading mask algorithm for radiation calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25709586/2521214)

   These are either:

   - **projected 2D maps** (hard to implement/use and often less precise)
   - **3D Voxel maps** (Memory demanding but easier to compute/use)

   Some approaches uses pre-rendered **Z-Buffer** as geometry source and then fill the lights via [Radiosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosity_(computer_graphics)) or any other technique. These can handle any number of lights as these maps can be computation demanding they are often computed in the background and updated once in a while.

   **fast moving light sources** are usually updated more often or excluded from maps and rendered as transparent geometry to make impression of light. The computational power needed for this depends on the computation method the basic are done like:

   - set a camera to the larges visible surfaces
   - render scene and handle the result as light/shadow map
   - store it as 2D or 3D texture or voxel map
   - and then continue with normal rendering from camera view

   So you need to render scene more then once per **frame/map** update and also need additional buffers to store the rendered result which for high resolution or Voxel maps can be a big chunk of memory.
4. **multi pass light layer**

   there are cases when light is added after rendering of the scene for example I used it for

   - [Atmospheric scattering in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19659648/2521214)

   Here comes all multi pass rendering techniques you need additional buffers to store the sub results and usually the multi pass rendering is done on the same view/scene so pre-rendered geometry is used which significantly speeds this up either as locked **VAO** or as already rendered **Z-buffer** Color and Index buffers from first pass. After this handle next passes as single or few Quads (like in the Atmospheric scattering link) so the computational power needed for this is not much bigger in comparison to basic **BR** rendering
5. **forward rendering vs. deferred-rendering**

   in a google this [forward rendering vs. deferred-rendering](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/forward-rendering-vs-deferred-rendering--gamedev-12342) is first relevant hit I found. It is not very good one (a bit to vague for my taste) but for starters it is enough

   - **forward rendering** techniques are usually standard single pass **BR** renders
   - **deffered rendering** is standard multi pass renders. In first pass is rendered all the geometries of the scene into Z buffer, Color buffer and some auxiliary buffers just to know which fragment of the result belongs to which object,material,... And then in the next passes are added effects,light,shadows,... but the geometry is not rendered again instead just single or few overlay QUADs/per pass are rendered so the next passes are usually pretty fast ...

   The link suggest that for high lights number is the deffered rendering more suited but that strongly depends on which of the previous technique is used. Usually the multi pass light layer is used (with is one of the standard deffered rendering techniques) so in that case it is true, and the memory and computational power demands are the same see the previous section.

Comment: I changed the title as per you suggestion, thank you.  How do these methods compare to forward and differed rendering in terms of speed and memory usage?  Also with the info Jerem gave concerning non constant for loop expressions, is passing in an array of light information and then a uniform for the number of lights a viable option compared to these methods or does that fall under BR rendering just with a non limited amount of lights.

Comment: @MatthewLudwig added requested info to each section of the answer. Just to be sure Forward and Deffered rendering are techniques how to render the output  from input provided by one of the techniques I list in answer. Deffered rendering is used for multi pass rendering and forward for standard BR rendering.

Comment: Thank you I couldn't have asked for anything better!  +1 and Accepted Answer!