# shadow algorithm for voxel based 3d city model

Tags: algorithm, components, shadow, voxel

I need to develop a component that analyzes shading times of voxels in 3d city model for every hour in a day for sun's position. What is the best shadowing algorithm or method for this purpose? Shadow mapping or ray tracing? Are there any components for this purpose. I don't know where to start. Any help would be very useful

Comment: Are there any extra constraints? For example, can there be voxels hanging in mid air? What about overhangs? Can the voxels be specified with a simple 2d height field? etc

Comment: see some related QAs here on SE first: [Shading mask algorithm for radiation calculations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25912210/2521214) and [What is the fastest shadowing algorithm (CPU only)?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22373855/2521214). I think the first is exactly the same task as yours even if the question is not duplicate.